# Query the contents of a Django model's JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, jsonb

I'm trying to figure out a way to query the data inside a postgres JSONField on a particular instance of my model.

From what I've seen, all the use cases are for things the equivalent of if you had an attributes JSONField, and then selecting all instances of your model where attributes ->> color = 'red' or whatever.

So let's give this a more real example, let's say we have a model `Shoe` and it has price and quantity and whatever as fields, but then also a JSONField called `versions`, which is an array of objects, each objects having the things that make each version special.

So if one instance of the Shoe model is Air Jordans, the attributes JSONField could look like:

```
[ 
    { 
        color: black, 
        edition: limited, 
        tongueColor: red 
    }, 
    { 
        color: black, 
        edition: standard 
    }, 
    { 
        color: gold, 
        edition: fancy, 
        bright: very 
    } 
]
```

So there's two things we can do, we can:

1. Query the Model for all shoes that have an available version with color: black (which would return our Air Jordans, plus maybe other shoes), or
2. Query the instance of the model for all objects inside the JSONField versions where color = black. So if we already had `Shoe.objects.filter(name='Air Jordans')` or something, could tack on some method or something at the end to just return the first two objects above where `color == black`?

I can find examples online of doing the first, but not the second.

I could just bring the object into memory and filter from there, but this JSONField is where I was hoping to store very large quantities of arbitrary data, and so being able to query without bringing the whole blob into memory is fairly important. Can JSONField support this?

Comment: how you know we can do the second thing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think you can do something like this `.filter(versions__contains={'color': 'black'})` or `.filter(versions__contains=[{'color': 'black'}])`. Otherwise you should probably create some custom lookup and use `json_to_recordset()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE

Comment: @valentjedi - I have no idea if this is possible, very possible it isn't.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard - `.filter` should return Shoe instances where I'm looking to return parts of the JSON blob. `json_to_recordset()` however looks like it does what I'm looking for. Will need to do some research into how to get that to play with Django's ORM, but definitely a great lead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AntoinePinsard pointed me in the right direction - json_to_recordset().

I'm currently using something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT j.* from shoes, json_to_recordset(json_field_name) as 
    j(color text, edition text, tongueColor: text, bright text) where 
    shoes.shoe_name = 'Air Jordan'
) subset
WHERE subset.color= "black"
```

So the inner select statement will build internally a recordset that looks like this:

```
color | edition  | tongueColor | bright
------+----------+-------------+--------
black | limited  | red         |
black | standard |             |
gold  | fancy    |             | very
```

and then the outer statement will query that internal recordset (in this case, where color = 'black' and will return:

```
color | edition  | tongueColor | bright
------+----------+-------------+--------
black | limited  | red         |
black | standard |             |
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Were you able to work this solution into the Django ORM ?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
Shoes.objects.filter(yourJsonFieldName__contains={'colors': 'black'})
```